# Can I say "name after the first letter"?

Tags: grammaticality

there.

I would like you guys to answer this question.

Let s say,

I had a dog named "Camila".

After she passed away I got a new dog.
(This dog is a male.)

I want to give him a name beginning with "C" from "Camila".

In this case, can I say

"I named him "Chris" after the first letter of "Camila"."?

Thanks!

Comment: (P.S: That's called eponym.)

Comment: I don't think there's any set phrase for doing that. Another way to describe it would be "I chose a name with the same initial."

Comment: Thank you so much Kate Bunting!!
Your sample sentence helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Another choice to what @Kate_Bunting has said can be,

> I chose the name 'Chris' for my dog since it has the same initial as
>   'Camilla'.

Comment: Aaron John Sabu, thank you so much!
It's easier to understand to me.